# How can I assign new value such as const, into new valuable in react class use state without using function component?

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks

I am just wondering how we get a value using useSelect or dispatch(react-redux) and assign to a new variable in react class component.

For example,

```
Class Login extends component{

  constructor(props){
  super(props);

     this.state = {
       example: test,
       example: test1,
       example: test2
     }

     /////and I want to call dispatch here But I got error "Hook can be called out side of the function"
      const dispatch = new useDispatch();
   }

  render(){
  return(

  <Button onclick = {() => dispatch(userconnetion)}></Button>

  )

  }

}
```

I don't want to use function component to solve this. Preferably, wanna use Class component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

useSelector and useDispatch are hooks, it only works in a functional component. You are using it in a class component. You either convert your component to a functional one or use mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps if you choose to stick with a class component.